# Headings interfering with Navbars

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website, also I am new to website programming, so I apologize if I got a few things wrong.

The h1 is appearing before my Navbar leaving the navbar below the heading. Any suggestions? Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <title>CSGOCarry | Contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="center">
        <h1>How To Contact Us</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Jackpot.asp">Jackpot</a></li>
        <li><a href="Coinflip.asp">Coinflip</a></li>
        <li><a href="Roulette.asp">Roulette</a></li>
        <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
          <li><a href="Contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.asp">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/login/">Sign In</a>
       </li>             
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

JSFiddle w/HTML & CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/fo0u1tcp/

Comment: The H1 appears below the header in your example fiddle ?

Comment: I have just updated the Fiddle, I posted the wrong one

Comment: Well, use that wrong then, if that works. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order that the `nav` and `container` appears in the document :

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Jackpot.asp">Jackpot</a></li>
    <li><a href="Coinflip.asp">Coinflip</a></li>
    <li><a href="Roulette.asp">Roulette</a></li>
    <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
      <li><a href="Contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.asp">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/login/">Sign In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
    <h1>How To Contact Us</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. I am new to HTML and CSS in general, have you got any helpful sources for a rookie?

Comment: Accept my answer and I'll be happy to give a few links ;)

Comment: I just did, it wouldn't let me at first because of the time limit haha :D

Comment: Thanks - Try these as a decent starting point : -                                     [Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction)                                     [HTMLDog](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/)